# spyOn(document, 'getElementById') throws error after upgrading to angular 8/"@types/jasmine": "^3.4.0"

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-upgrade

The below code throws error after upgrading to "@types/jasmine": "^3.4.0"

```
spyOn(document, 'getElementById').and.callFake(function() {
      return {
        value: 'test'
      };
    });
```

Error is:

```
Argument of type '() => { value: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(elementId: string) => HTMLElement'.
  Type '{ value: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 233 more.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting to fix the issue.

```
spyOn(document, 'getElementById').and.callFake(function(elementId: string) {
      return {
        value: 'test'
      } as HTMLElement;
    });
```